# How to sync gitlab with github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have several developers working on a local Gitlab instance. The client requires that their Github repo is kept updated. So our Gitlab repo should push any commits directly to Github. Any commits to Github should likewise be pulled into Gitlab.

I could do the first part (dev --> gitlab --> github) with jenkins or something, but am stuck on the reverse. Our Gitlab and Jenkins run inside our firewall.

Any hints or pointers (or drop in solutions!) would be very appreciated.

Comment: can't you run a process on a dev machine that pushes to github ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<strike>It's only in the enterprise edition and on GitLab.com, but</strike> GitLab has introduced this feature directly, without any workarounds.

They've documented pulling/pushing from/to a remote repository in [GitLab Docs → User Docs → Projects → Repositories → Mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html).

It's in the same section of configuration that you can push, too:

1. From within a project use the gear icon to select **Mirror Repository**
2. Scroll down to **Push to a remote repository**
3. Checkmark **Remote mirror repository**: Automatically update the remote mirror's branches, tags, and commits from this repository every hour.
4. Enter the repository you want to update; for GitHub you can include your username and password in the URL, like so: `https://yourgithubusername:yourgithubpassword@github.com/agaric/guts_discuss_resource.git`

Note that I haven't tried it, but you should be able to push to and pull from the same repository.  It's working great for me pulling from a remote repository (drupal.org), and pushing to a different remote repository (gitlab.com).

Comment: Is there any solution for Gitlab-CE ?

Comment: I can have repo mirror feature in my free gitlab repo

Comment: update documentation from GITLAB 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html

Comment: Link in answer and link in the comment above are no longer valid

Answer (score 9):

All answers, including my old one before this edit  (*14 dec 2023*) are now outdated.

New info:
For syncing to/from github you can now find the full info here in the docs at *"Use GitLab → Manage your code → Repositories → Mirroring"* and here you can choose for [Pull mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html) or [Push mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/push.html).

Comment: The link in mlnc's answer points to the same page anyway.

Comment: Link outdated :/

Comment: Thanks for warning me, I updated them

Answer (score 5):

For syncing from GitHub to GitLab you could use the [Webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) to send a notification to your site and possibly manage this somehow (although I don't know if GitLab supports this out of the box).

And with a bit more implementation you could (theoretically) use the GitHub API.

I also found a [small script](https://gist.github.com/jakimowicz/4079496) named "simple (and dirty) sync between redmine issues and gitlab issues" which should do at least this.